# How to convert pcap that contains a RTP stream to .raw

Tags: python, stream, rtp, pcap, sox

I am working on a python script that will take a pcap, will save the individual RTP Streams and will then use sox to convert that RTP stream into a wav file.
Now, I am able to use tshark to create pcap files that each contain one rtp stream but i am not able to convert those pcaps into .raw files so that I can use sox to create wav files.
The .raw files can be created by opening the file in wireshark Telephony -> RTP -> stream analysis -> save (File Synchronized forward stream audio).

Is there a way to either use tshark or any other python library (preferably) to convert the pcap (that contains one stream) to raw.

See attached pcap file that contains one stream, I want to convert it to raw.

Comment: File link is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O1LaS02fbtFOWlOD8JaIGqrYn47Dobpd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

if u just need hex dump of PCAP

```
tshark -x -r mydata.pcap | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

Comment: Amit, thanks for the answer. I have already tried that and there hex dump produced is not identical to the file created by Wireshark save as raw. The resulting was file by this process can't be heard properly