# Extract RTP stream from a pcap session

Tags: python, shell, wireshark, pcap, sox

I am working on a way to extract one stream from a pcap session file using (preferably) Python. I read many questions, links and tutorial such as :

[How to convert pcap that contains a RTP stream to .raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865741/how-to-convert-pcap-that-contains-a-rtp-stream-to-raw) from 3 years ago

[AudioScraper](https://github.com/wbwarnerb/AudioScraper/blob/master/pcap_reader.py) by Brian Warmer

[pcap2wav](https://gist.github.com/avimar/d2e9d05e082ce273962d742eb9acac16)

`AudioScraper` did allow me to extract the RTP stream from the pcap, but I have **4** RTP streams and I have no idea which one has been extracted. `pcap2wav` was able to select a specific stream. In both cases, the sound is unrecognizable when I play the output file in audacity.

I am still as of today trying to find an automated way to extract specific RTP streams from a pcap file using Python..

### EDIT 1

I give up limiting myself to Python answers. I found this answer by Brian Warner using a shell script :

```
ssrc=$(sudo tshark -n -r "capture.pcap" -Y rtp -T fields -e rtp.ssrc -Eseparator=, | sort -u)
# [-n disable network object name resolution] 
# [-r read file]
# [-Y read filter applied during first pass. Packets not matching the filter are not considered for future passes]
# [-T format of the output when viewing decoded packet data. fields specified with the -e option]

echo $ssrc
# 0x170e45b8 0x210f90ea 0x302a4ef0 0x6c1acefa

sudo tshark -n -r "capture.pcap" -Y rtp -Y "rtp.ssrc==$ssrc" -T fields -e rtp.payload | tee payloads
for payload in `cat payloads`; do 
  IFS=:;
  
  for byte in $payload;do 
    printf"\\x$byte" >> sound.raw;
  done;
done;

sudo sox -t raw -r 8000 -c 1 sound.raw capture3d.wav
```

Unfortunately it doesnt' work...

```
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
0x170e45b8 0x210f90ea 0x302a4ef0 0x6c1acefa
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
tshark: "0x210f90ea" was unexpected in this context.
sox FAIL formats: can't open input file `sound.raw': No such file or directory
```

I have little knowledge in shell, can you spot my mistakes ?

Answer (score 0):

It's C/C++ not Python but [this Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/u/signalogic) has a command line tool called mediaMin that handles pcaps with multiple concurrent RTP streams, different codecs, and streams that create child streams per RFC8108.  Some [doc on the cmd line](https://github.com/signalogic/SigSRF_SDK/blob/master/mediaTest_readme.md#user-content-dynamicsessioncreation) is here. If you use an .sdp file in the command line you can pull out only the stream you want

Disclaimer: I work for the company that created this tool

Comment: I no longer work on this project so I can't test your solution.